Dependency injection composition root dependent on configuration value
In my startup I have a to choose between one of two startup Extension methods dependent on a configuration value (a feature flag).
Normally if it was a composition of one interface as a singleton I would use the version of AddSingleton() where I can specify a lambda function as a parameter, and I would get something like this:
        services.AddSingleton<ISomeInterface>(provider =>
        {
            var featureFlags = provider.GetRequiredService<IFeatureFlagsHandler>();
            if (featureFlags.IsFeatureEnabled(FeatureX))
                return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Implementation1>(provider);
            else
                return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Implementation2>(provider);
        });

But what if my composition was defined on two startup extensions defined in a 3rd part module, who can I do it then. I am thinking of something like
        services.CallComposer(provider =>
        {
            var featureFlags = provider.GetRequiredService<IFeatureFlagsHandler>();
            if (featureFlags.IsFeatureEnabled(FeatureX))
                services.AddCompositionOfClassesThatSupportFeatureX();
            else
                services.AddCompositionOfClassesThatSupportOldFeature();
        });

Is that possible? I have learnt that it is bad practice to call services.BuildServiceProvider() and use that to get the instance of the IFeatureFlagsHandler

What DI container/library are you using?

Not sure actually. It is the default DI library which comes with .Net. not sure if it has a name.

Check the namespaces of the methods I call I find this namespace "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection". So I assume that answers your question

Is it essential to use the IoC container to resolve an instance of IFeatureFlagsHandler? If not, you could forego the need to wrap the if within the factory method.

Use a factory or just intermediate provider of your service, so you can inject there whatever and how much services you like in order to decide which implementation should be returned. It's up to whether you do it in a dedicated service or services configuration.
